# Use different components depending on a property of a model

Tags: ember.js

In my Ember app I created one model with a color property

```
   App.Gecko = DS.Model.extend({
       color: fusia

    })
```

In the templates, I want to run different components depending on the color of the Gecko, so the desired logic in my templates is like this

```
 {{#each item in model}}
       {{if item.color == green}}
             code for a component
       {{/if}}
       {{if item.color == blue}}
            code for some other component
       {{/if}}
 {{/each}}
```

Except that Handlebars doesn't support the {{ if item.color == green }} logic. I understand that I'm supposed to use computed properties for this, but I can't figure out how to set it up so that different components would run depending on the color of the item. Question: How would I use a computed property on my controller (I'm assuming it belongs in the controller) to run different components depending on a property in the model?

Update 
In response to the first answer, I tried to use the new (as of 1.11) component helper following the pattern shown in the commit https://github.com/lukemelia/ember.js/commit/16b70236e0904cc76335c34fae8ef2c035b0657b  This is how I called it

```
{{#each item in model}}
    {{ component renderGeckoComponent model=item }}

{{/each}}
```

In my controller, I had this

```
   renderGeckoComponent: function(){
    var col = this.get('model.color');
     console.log("even though there are many instances, this only runs once and ")
    if (color === "fusia"){
      console.log("going to have a component here")
    }else if (color === "pink"){
      console.log("going to have a component here")
   }
   }.property('model.color')
```

Result:  When I try to get the property to switch on, it says `undefined`

```
var col = this.get('model.color');  //col is undefined
console.log(col) //undefined
```

Comment: You have: `var col = this.get('model.color');` -- but then you're checking `if (color === "fusia") {` .. one is `col` one is `color`...

Answer (score 2):

In regards to supporting `val1 == val2` there is a addon: [ember-truth-helpers](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers)

To use a computed property to dynamically create a component, there is the [{{component}} helper](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/03/27/ember-1-11-0-released.html#toc_component-helper).

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Instead of merely linking do you mind showing how to use it. I tried to follow the pattern in the commit message but wasn't able to access the property  that I would need to switch on. See update and  https://github.com/lukemelia/ember.js/commit/16b70236e0904cc76335c34fae8ef2c035b0657b